# Classic ASP: Cache XML Document in Application Context

Tags: caching, asp-classic, vbscript

So we have an ASP script to answer simple AJAX search requests. The data to be searched is stored in an XML document. It would be wasteful to parse this doc over and over again. It is sufficient and fastest to parse it once, read the data in memory (a couple thousand string entries, not more), and then reply from memory.

So this is like an initialization task. On startup (or first run), the script has to load the data; on subsequent requests, use it.

How do you code such an init taks in an ASP script? Do I need a `Global.asa` file? Or can I have logic in my script that checks for the presence of an object in `Application.Contents` to create and store in if not present?

Here's my code, which tries to cache the doc, but fails to achieve this objective:

```
<%
Option Explicit

Sub PrintNodes( xmlDoc )
    For Each node In xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//item")
        key = node.GetAttribute("id")
        value = node.ChildNodes(0).ChildNodes(0).Text
        Response.Write( key & ": " & value & VbNewline )
    Next
End Sub

Dim locale, cacheKey, xmlFile, xmlDoc, node, key, value

locale = "de_CH" ' Vorgabe
cacheKey = "doc." & locale

Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
Response.Write( cacheKey & VbNewline )

If Not Application( cacheKey ) Then
    xmlFile = Server.MapPath( locale & "/kat.all.xml" )
    Response.Write( xmlFile & VbNewline )
    Set xmlDoc = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument.6.0")
    xmlDoc.load( xmlFile )
    If xmlDoc.parseError.errorcode <> 0 Then
        Response.Write("XML Error" & VbNewline )
    Else
        PrintNodes( xmlDoc )
        Application.Lock
        Application( cacheKey ) = xmlDoc
        Application.Unlock
    End If
Else
    Response.Write( "Jetzt ELSE!" & VbNewline )
    Application.Lock
    Set xmlDoc = Application( cacheKey )
    PrintNodes( xmlDoc )
    Application.Unlock
End If

%>
```

Samples in JScript or PerlScript (ActiveState PerlScript extension) also welcome.

Comment: Where fails? the content is never cached? I think you should serialize and deserialize the XML

Comment: @Eduardo, the reason the above doesn't work is that the condition `If Not Application( cacheKey ) Then` would work in Perl and other languages, but in VBScript you need to be more precise: for an object, you'd want `IsObject()`, and for a string you'd want `IsEmpty()`. Hence my impression caching didn't work. The code just never branched to `ELSE`. Once that got fixed, the other error showed up. See my comments to jsobo's reply below.

Comment: About the boolean gotcha that trapped me here: [Not Logical Is VBScript](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/07/15/184431.aspx) - "Conditional statements should always take Booleans. Or, in other words, use Booleans as Booleans, use nothing else as Booleans." - Use the form `If bla Then` *only* if you know that `bla` is a boolean; in all other cases, use an explicit comparison in the conditional to obtain a boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using set...

```
 SET Application( cacheKey ) = xmlDoc
```

also you should use the following to see if an object exists.

```
If Application( cacheKey ) is nothing Then
```

Alternatively you could load the doc object in your global.asa using
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524620(v=vs.90).aspx

```
<OBJECT RUNAT=Server SCOPE=Application ID=XmlDoc PROGID="MSXML2.DomDocument.6.0"></OBJECT>
```

NOTE: SCOPE=Application is important.

But then you would have to check somehow to see if you already loaded the object... which you could cheat and just put something like this in your initialization code.

```
If Application("IAlreadyLoadedTheXmlDoc") <> "TRUE" THEN
   '  --- load the doc
    Dim xmlfile
    xmlFile = Server.MapPath( locale & "/kat.all.xml" )
    xmlDoc.load( xmlFile )
    Application("IAlreadyLoadedTheXmlDoc") = "TRUE"
End If
```

OK... EDIT for the apparment threaded thing...

USE this guy to cache your object in... 
http://www.miniat.net/caprock-dictionary-object-component.asp

Comment: `Set` for assigning an object, correct, thanks. Makes me bump into the next error, a real one this time: `ASP 0197 : 80004005 - Cannot add object with apartment model behavior to the application`. In a nutshell, I think this is because I'm trying to share among multiple threads (in the `Application`) an object that's not prepared to be treated that way. So ASP disallows that straight away to avoid concurrency issues. Very good. Have to check on the VBScript syntax. Then, two things to try: (1) sharing just the text (good enough), (2) sharing a free-threaded XML doc instance (interesting).

Comment: WOW you are taking me way back to 2000... I can't believe I remember that old dictionary object... ;-)

Comment: Hehe. I LOVE outdated technology :) Actually, ASP is not bad at all. Nice and compact, well suited for scripts and small apps. Fast. Even VBScript is not too bad ... once you agree to accept the quirks. I even like `cmd.exe` and `sqlplus` and such tools ... - Okay, news from the front: (1) sharing just the text (`xmlDoc.xml`) obviously works; (2) sharing a `MSXML2.FreeThreadedDomDocument.6.0` also works; (3) `Application.Lock/Unlock` is, I *think*, only required when writing to the cache; (4) when using the free-threaded doc has its own locking, so no extra locking required when querying it.

Comment: For posterity, [here's the reference on `Application.Lock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525184.aspx). And from March 2000, ["XML-based Persistence Behaviors Fix Web Farm Headaches"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302344.aspx). And Chapter 13 of "XML Application Development with MSXML 4.0", Wrox 2002.